# Proper usage of "engendered"

Tags: verbs, word-usage, dictionaries

"His actions engendered a revolution in the Capitol."

This sounds a bit off to me. But going by the dictionary meaning, this is legal and correct. Is this correct in terms of readability and conveying meaning? If not, please help me starighten out this sentence. (I do not need alternative words.)

Comment: To engender: 
 to cause to exist or to develop :  produce *policies that have engendered controversy* (M-W).   "*Lenin proposed the vanguard party of the proletariat on the following grounds. The irreconcilable contradictions of capitalism would  **engender a revolution***  and make socialism possible."*     https://books.google.it/books?id=2KTaAAAAMAAJ&q=%22engender+a+revolution%22&dq=%22engender+a+revolution%22&hl=it&sa=X&ei=GJ6CVbWjBMSuU-WGgcgD&ved=0CDcQ6AEwAw

Comment: What do you find by Googling "engendered a revolution" (note that past-tense examples are often more common)?

Answer (score 2):

To cause something other than biological offspring to come into existence is a figurative meaning of the word. But figuratively is how it is has long been used; the literal meaning is faint or lost to most speakers nowadays, so that many readers won't perceive it to be figurative, but a few might.

The trope is a commonplace, BTW.  *The seeds of revolution...*

So this is a question of the *mot juste* which you'll have to take up with your inner Author. Alternative neutral terms without the  baggage are *brought about* and *caused* and *led to*.